# Select different values that has the same column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've read many `SQL` queries and tried these but not succeed to do what I want. I want a `SQL` Query that take in parameters random members ids, and return if they have a conversation in common :

```
SELECT
  conversation_id
FROM conversation_mapping
WHERE user_id IN ('1902616933097029', '1112126462227347', '26544849', '13587745')
GROUP BY conversation_id
HAVING COUNT(conversation_id) <> 1
```

Which gives me this result :

```
38
39
```

The result is not good at all because in the ids '1902616933097029', '1112126462227347', '26544849', '13587745 have not at all two conversation in common.

My table

```
---------------------------------------
|    user_id       | conversation_id  |
---------------------------------------
|'1112126462227347'| 38               |
|"1112126462227347"| 39               |
|"13587445"        | 39               |
|"1902616933097029"| 38               |
|"1902616933097029"| 39               |
|"26544849"        | 38               |
|"26544849"        | 39               |
|"8541245"         | 38               |
---------------------------------------
```

**The problem with the `IN` statement is that it finds id1 OR id2 OR id3, and didn't select id1 AND id2 AND id3 that has the same conversation id**

Comment: Please give example of the wanted output.

Comment: For the values '1902616933097029', '1112126462227347', '26544849', '13587745', it should return 39, the only conversation the Ids have in common

Comment: For PostgreSQL: `HAVING array_agg(user_id) @> ARRAY['1902616933097029', '1112126462227347', '26544849', '13587745']`

Comment: @AlexM, which dbms is that for? (Note that no dbms is specified.)

Comment: For some reasons, the ids are not integer types. I use PostgreSQL

Comment: @sql_newbie_developper check again, please. I fixed the query (it shoud be `array_agg(user_id)`)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want conversations that have *all* the ids in common.  If so, use a `having` clause:

```
SELECT conversation_id
FROM conversation_mapping
WHERE user_id IN ('1902616933097029', '1112126462227347', '26544849', '13587745')
GROUP BY conversation_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) = 4;
```

The "4" is the number of users in the `IN` list.

Comment: This works great and returns the result as expected. Thank you.

Comment: There is a problem if there is another conversation which contains N ids. The query returns the id of the conversation whereas the N are in, but there are N + Y participants, so it finally does not work for what i want.

Comment: @sql_newbie_developper . . . It is only possible to answer the question that you ask:  "Query that take in parameters random members ids, and return if they have a conversation in common".  That is what this answer does.  If you have a different question, then ask it as a new question, with sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation.

Answer (score 0):

In table you have "13587**4**45", but search for 13587**7**45

Check values in "where" condition and do so

```
SELECT
  conversation_id
FROM conversation_mapping
WHERE user_id IN ('1902616933097029', '1112126462227347', '26544849', '13587445')
GROUP BY conversation_id
HAVING COUNT(conversation_id) = 4;
```